# FSMs extraction with yosys

Tags: fpga, yosys

I have been trying to use yosys in order to extract FSMs from my structural verilog file (gate library is simprims of Xilinx) with no success. I figured I might need to inform yosys which gate library I use or something similar, but as I said, no success.
Is there anything I should do in order to make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more details? Any code to share?

Answer (score 0):

Yosys' FSM extraction is designed to extract FSMs from coarse grain RTL-derived netlists. It is not going to be able to extract FSMs from technology-mapped netlists, this would need a different approach.

Comment: Thank you!
Doesn't yosys support structural verilog at all? Is there anything I can do (maybe converting the design to a different format?) in order to use yosys' tools (fsm extraction, optimizations, etc)? or structural verilog files are just not supported?

Thanks again!

Comment: Yosys supports structural Verilog. It is the FSM passes in Yosys that only work on directly RTL-derived netlists

Comment: I had no luck with optimizing the design through yosys, it couldn't even recognize I had muxes although I had. Except writing my design into other formats (such as AIGER, EDIF) I couldn't really do anything.

Comment: You might need to read in the cell definitions using read_liberty or read_verilog, followed by hierarchy and flatten

Comment: However, that will cause the original mapping to be lost, as it will replace cells with their implementations.